# How can I fix a straight line prediction issue in ARIMA forecasting with Python?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast the AQI values for 2019. I am training my model on 2017 and 2018 data and am/attempting to forecast the year 2019. However, it always results in a straight line prediction. My target variable is dfdaily['AQI_stationary'], the data in there is already stationary. How can I fix this, I want actual predictions and not a straight line?This is my code, my ACF and PACF plots and my results:

`df = df_daily.reset_index()[['DatetimeBegin', 'AQI_stationary']]`

`df.columns = ['DatetimeBegin', 'AQI_stationary']`

`df.set_index('DatetimeBegin', inplace=True)`

`df.dropna(inplace=True)`

`# Select data for training and testing`

`train = df[(df.index.year >= 2017) & (df.index.year <= 2018)]`

`test = df[df.index.year == 2019]`

`# Define the order of the ARIMA model`

`p = 1`

`d = 0`

`q = 6`

`# Fit the ARIMA model`

`model = ARIMA(train['AQI_stationary'], order=(p, d, q))`

`model_fit = model.fit()`

`# Perform predictions for 2019`

`predictions = model_fit.predict(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31')`

`# Plot the actual and predicted values`

`plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))`

`plt.plot(train.index, train['AQI_stationary'], label='Train')`

`plt.plot(test.index, test['AQI_stationary'], label='Actual')`

`plt.plot(predictions.index, predictions, label='Predicted')`

`plt.xlabel('Date')`

`plt.ylabel('Total AQI')`

`plt.legend()`

`plt.show()`

[ACF and PACF plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yVpE.png)

[Predictions vs actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp8rt.jpg)

I tried the auto ARIMA function to use the parameters, but it resulted in the same results